# Azure C++ library: "Invalid streambuf object"

Tags: c++, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to download a potentially huge Azure block blob, using the C++ Azure client library.  It isn't working because I don't know how to initialize a concurrency::streams::streambuf object with a buffer size.  My code looks like this:

```
 // Assume blockBlob has been created correctly.
 concurrency::streams::istream blobStream = blockBlob.open_read();
 // I don't know how to initialize this streambuf:         
 concurrency::streams::streambuf<uint8_t> dlStreamBuf;
 size_t nBytesReturned = 0, nBytesToRead = 65536;
 do {
    // This gets the exception "Invalid streambuf object": 
    concurrency::task<size_t> returnedTask = blobStream.read(dlStreamBuf, nBytesToRead);
    nBytesReturned = returnedTask.get();
    bytesSoFar += nBytesReturned;
    // Process the data in dlStreamBuf here...
 } while(nBytesReturned > 0);
 blobStream.close();
```

Note that the above streambuf is not to be confused with a standard C++ streambuf.

Can anyone advise me on how to properly construct and initialize a concurrency::streams::streambuf?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

streambuf seems to be a template class. Try this instead:

```
    concurrency::streams::container_buffer<std::vector<uint8_t>> output_buffer;
    size_t nBytesReturned = 0, nBytesToRead = 65536;
    do {
        // This gets the exception "Invalid streambuf object": 
        concurrency::task<size_t> returnedTask = stream.read(output_buffer, nBytesToRead);
        nBytesReturned = returnedTask.get();
        bytesSoFar += nBytesReturned;
        // Process the data in dlStreamBuf here...
    } while (nBytesReturned > 0);
    stream.close();
```

Sample code is here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-cpp/blob/76cb553249ede1e6f05456d936c9a36753cc1597/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage/tests/blob_streams_test.cpp#L192

Comment: Thanks, @sguler! That does compile.  Now I am trying to figure out how to get the data in output_buffer into a real buffer (array of unsigned char)...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the stream methods for C++, but there are two ways mentioned in the C++ documentation about downloading to files or to steams **[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-c-plus-plus-how-to-use-blobs#how-to-download-blobs)**

The **download_to_stream method ex:**

```
    // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
azure::storage::cloud_storage_account storage_account = azure::storage::cloud_storage_account::parse(storage_connection_string);

// Create the blob client.
azure::storage::cloud_blob_client blob_client = storage_account.create_cloud_blob_client();

// Retrieve a reference to a previously created container.
azure::storage::cloud_blob_container container = blob_client.get_container_reference(U("my-sample-container"));

// Retrieve reference to a blob named "my-blob-1".
azure::storage::cloud_block_blob blockBlob = container.get_block_blob_reference(U("my-blob-1"));

// Save blob contents to a file.
concurrency::streams::container_buffer<std::vector<uint8_t>> buffer;
concurrency::streams::ostream output_stream(buffer);
blockBlob.download_to_stream(output_stream);

std::ofstream outfile("DownloadBlobFile.txt", std::ofstream::binary);
std::vector<unsigned char>& data = buffer.collection();

outfile.write((char *)&data[0], buffer.size());
outfile.close();
```

**Alternative**, using download_to_file:

```
    // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
azure::storage::cloud_storage_account storage_account = azure::storage::cloud_storage_account::parse(storage_connection_string);

// Create the blob client.
azure::storage::cloud_blob_client blob_client = storage_account.create_cloud_blob_client();

// Retrieve a reference to a previously created container.
azure::storage::cloud_blob_container container = blob_client.get_container_reference(U("my-sample-container"));

// Retrieve reference to a blob named "my-blob-2".
azure::storage::cloud_block_blob text_blob = container.get_block_blob_reference(U("my-blob-2"));

// Download the contents of a blog as a text string.
utility::string_t text = text_blob.download_text();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm hoping for a buffer-by-buffer "read"-type interface, to match the way the application works today.  Still researching...